# Do an automatic request

Tags: angularjs, rest, input, service

Im working on angularJS.

I have an input connected to a service who serves a postal code. (in my case all the zip codes have 5 numbers)

I want that when I put the 5th number, it makes the call without press a button.

My service is this:

```
angular
.module('myApp') 
.controller('codPostal', codPostal);

 function  codPostal($scope, $http, $rootScope) {
  $scope.SendCP = function () {        
        var config = {
            headers : {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8;'
            }
        }
        $http({
            method:'GET',
            url:'https://postal-code.service.com/' + $scope.formData.domicilio.codPostal,

            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        })
        .success(function ( data, status, headers, config) {
            $rootScope.cpResponse = data;

        })
        .error(function (data, status, header, config) {
            $scope.CPdetails = "Data: " + data +
                "<hr />status: " + status +
                "<hr />headers: " + header +
                "<hr />config: " + config;
        });
    };
```

}

I use a 'SendCP' as trigger to get the response.

Comment: Add a listener on key up, count characters, as soon as it is equals to 5, make call to service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ng-change on any input that has an ng-model and when the model is updated due to a user event (key up) the ng-change will fire, in there you can check if the length of the string matches 5 and if so fire your function.

```js
angular.module('myApp',[])
.controller('myCtrl', function($scope){

  $scope.SendCP = function(){ alert('do existing thing here')}
  
  $scope.zipCodeHandler = function(zipcode){
    if(zipcode.length==5)
      $scope.SendCP();
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-controller="myCtrl">

  <input ng-model="zipCodeHere" ng-change="zipCodeHandler(zipCodeHere)"/>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I don't know. Your ng-model is bound to $scope, you don't need to pass it as a parameter though.

Comment: Yeah just depends on the interface you want for the function figured this would be more straightforward to test.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was a very useful solution. =)